# How do I get the first value of a DirectoryStream without using a loop

Tags: java, stream, nio

```
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream( DirectoryPath, ".txt" );
```

I have a directory stream that holds all the text files found in the specified Directory path. How can I retrieve the first value of this stream without using a loop?

Comment: Do you mean `"*.txt"` or do you really intent to look for the sole file named `".txt"` only? In the latter case, you should use `DirectoryPath.resolve(".txt")` and `Files.exists`…

Comment: yes, I meant "*.txt", sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning only the first found entry:

```
Files.newDirectoryStream( DirectoryPath, ".txt" ).iterator().next()
```

You may also want to check if there is even at least one file before calling `next()`:

```
Iterator<Path> textFileIterator = Files.newDirectoryStream( DirectoryPath, ".txt" ).iterator();
if (textFileIterator.hasNext()) {
  Path firstFoundTextFile = textFileIterator.next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!